# matplotlib - AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a newbie to python and i am trying to learn online. I tried importing matplotlib on python 3.6 but i keep getting this error:

problem in matplotlib - AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'.

I am using Anaconda. and i have installed the matplotlib library too. I have no idea what is going on. Please help.

Comment: As your question stands it would be very difficult to know where to start. Can you provide the code you are running which results in the error?

Comment: Just a guess: Did you call one of your files numbers.py?

Comment: Thanks Matt for your response. the code I used is import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: And yes, @datasailor, one of my files is named numbers.py. I have just renamed that file and now, it works without errors. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As you told us in your comment, your file is named numbers.py. This file is probably the problem, as it hides the numbers.py file used by matplotlib. Your numbers.py file does not provide the Integral attribute, thus the error message.
Solution: Rename your file.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a bunch